# Is there a way to store large JSON in solr without tokenizing and get it in complex solr function?

Tags: solr

I am trying to use this field

```
<fieldType name="json" class="solr.TextField"
           positionIncrementGap="100">
</fieldType>
<field name='json_field' type="json" indexed="true" stored="true"
      omitNorms="false" required="false" multiValued="false"/>
```

I have to get value of this json field in my complex function

```
FunctionValues json =this.json_field.getValues(context, readerContext);
```

I then try to get the entire json

```
json.strVal(doc)
```

But then, I get only partial tokens.

If I try to use

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

I get ERROR

> "SOLR doesn't accept token larger than 32766"

Comment: Please show us an example what you have inside json_field" ? (json)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is basically, that if you're using `KeywordTokenizer` for a big text, it will try to create 1 big token, which is obviously limited.

```
/**
   * Absolute hard maximum length for a term, in bytes once
   * encoded as UTF8.  If a term arrives from the analyzer
   * longer than this length, an
   * <code>IllegalArgumentException</code>  is thrown
   * and a message is printed to infoStream, if set (see {@link
   * IndexWriterConfig#setInfoStream(InfoStream)}).
   */
  public final static int MAX_TERM_LENGTH = DocumentsWriterPerThread.MAX_TERM_LENGTH_UTF8;
```

There is no way to get full json, rather save it as not analyzed, e.g set `indexed=false`, but then you will not be able to search through this json, it will only be stored as is. Is it really what you need?